# SQL - 'Where exists' clause without equality check

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Can someone explain what this syntax is doing:

```
where exists(select * from table(source.sources))
```

I dont understand how the comparison takes place. The syntax i am used to is

```
Select x
from y
where exists (select 1 from z where z.id = y.id)
```

In the first exists statement, where does the y.id = x.id comparison take place? Can i see an example of how the first syntax can be used?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `sources` is a nested table in the `source` table. Here's an example:

```
create type sources_type as table of number
/

create table source (id number, sources sources_type)
nested table sources store as sources_tab;

insert into source (id, sources) values (1, null);
insert into source (id, sources) values (2, sources_type());
insert into source (id, sources) values (3, sources_type(1, 2, 3));
```

The three rows are the three possible states of `sources`; null, an empty table (which is not the same thing), and a populated table. If you want to select rows where the table is not empty, you can't check if it's null as that is only half the story.

```
select * from source
where sources is null;

        ID SOURCES                                
---------- ----------------------------------------
         1                                          

select * from source
where sources is not null;

        ID SOURCES                                
---------- ----------------------------------------
         2 STACKOVERFLOW.SOURCES_TYPE()             
         3 STACKOVERFLOW.SOURCES_TYPE(1,2,3)
```

You might not want the row with `id=2` included. So you can look at the nested table contents instead:

```
select * from source
where not exists (select * from table(sources));

        ID SOURCES                                
---------- ----------------------------------------
         1                                          
         2 STACKOVERFLOW.SOURCES_TYPE()             

select * from source
where exists (select * from table(sources));

        ID SOURCES                                
---------- ----------------------------------------
         3 STACKOVERFLOW.SOURCES_TYPE(1,2,3)
```

So that final query is ignoring empty nested tables, as well as nulls.

In your second example you're doing a correlated subquery (or at least I assume you would be if the pseudocode wan't a bit mangled), looking for matching data in a table which is not part of the main query, and which does (usually) need the equality test; in the first example you're checking for the existence of data within the same table, so there is nothing to compare against.

You can also check for specific values in the nested table as well - I'm not sure if that clarifies or confuses the issue:

```
select * from source
where exists (select * from table(sources) where column_value = 2);
```

Comment: ah ok i see what it is doing. Thanks for the detailed explanation.